# Ghosting keys appeared in gnuplot map

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I wanted to use gnuplot to plot wind direction and in one region, but there were two keys appearing on the map, I didn't know how to work it out. The number of Data is too big, I can't stick them, I feel sorry about that. [1:97][1:88] is the domain of that region.

```
set terminal postscript portrait color enhanced 12
set output "wind.ps"
set pm3d corners2color c1 map
set palette defined (0 0 0 1, 0.5 1 1 1, 1 1 0 0)
set multiplot
unset xtics
unset ytics
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0.5
set bmargin 0
set size 1,0.5
set size ratio 0.80745
set origin 0,0.2
set key at 92,13 title "Difference"
set title "(a) Test Wind Field"
splot "wind.txt" u ($1):($2):(1):($3):($4):(1) w vec lt 1 notitle
splot [1:97][1:88] "counrty.txt" u ((($1)-282)/12)+1:((($2)+906)/12)+1:1 notitle  w l lt -1 lw 0.5
unset label
```

[image]

If I add [1:97][1:88] to the command line of wind, the ghosting key disappeared while unwanted lines appeared.

```
splot [1:97][1:88] "wind.txt" u ($1):($2):(1):($3):($4):(1) w vec lt 1 notitle
```

wind direction after add [1:97][1:88]

[image]

If I use the command 'plot' to plot the wind direction, then it will be like that.

```
plot  "yrd.wind.covid19.txt" u ($1):($2):($3):($4) w vec lt 1 notitle
```

[the third situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20eFX.png)

If removed the [1:97][1:88], it will be the map displayed below.

```
splot "counrty.txt" u ((($1)-282)/12)+1:((($2)+906)/12)+1:1 notitle  w l lt -1 lw 0.5,\
      "yrd.wind.covid19.txt" u ($1):($2):(1):($3):($4):(1) w vec lt 1 notitle
```

[the forth situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li1z0.png)

This is the data file of wind direction.

```
   1           1   1.108715      -1.988065    
   1           7 -0.2828265      -2.514480    
   1          13 -0.5162781      -2.534442    
   1          19 -0.8041242      -2.118783    
   1          25  -1.005743      -2.119185    
   1          31  -1.385974      -2.011106    
   1          37  -1.303812      -1.727541    
   1          43  -1.198456      -2.012927    
   1          49 -0.8044212      -1.074293    
   1          55  -1.169173     -0.9435396    
   1          61 -0.4521698     -0.8306611    
   1          67 -0.3398472     -0.9110256    
   1          73  0.5497940     -0.4957737    
   1          79 -0.4249686     -0.6902521    
   1          85 -0.4333920     -0.2701551    
   7           1 -0.1291364       1.197334    
   7           7  -1.620592      -1.361079    
   7          13  -1.087388      -1.573736    
   7          19  -1.024136      -1.235521    
   7          25  -1.517918      -1.773767    
   7          31 -0.9683833      -1.493137    
   7          37  -1.105461      -1.764376    
   7          43  -1.145569      -1.821003    
   7          49  -1.238689      -1.697086    
   7          55 -0.5481215      -1.310746    
   7          61 -0.3959183     -0.8476363    
   7          67 -0.5949239     -0.5122660    
   7          73 -0.4818483     -0.4196534    
   7          79 -0.7659698     -0.6680192    
   7          85  0.1679092     -0.5400997    
  13           1  0.1285889      -1.156056    
  13           7  -1.094984      -1.434627    
  13          13 -0.7929572      -1.323432    
  13          19  -1.180756      -1.600855    
  13          25 -0.8877360      -1.613529    
  13          31 -0.9996457      -1.527605    
  13          37 -0.8238124      -1.481949    
  13          43 -0.7603424      -1.890813    
  13          49  -1.025161     -0.9066794    
  13          55  -1.015571      -1.118257    
  13          61 -0.9035642     -0.7665278    
  13          67 -0.8321055     -0.4831027    
  13          73 -0.5451021     -0.3968017    
  13          79 -0.3045120     -0.3047466    
  13          85 -0.2497719     -0.2208077    
  19           1 -0.4189178      -1.090045    
  19           7 -0.8407141      -1.320205    
  19          13 -0.7748231      -1.871686    
  19          19  -1.469146      -2.367272    
  19          25 -0.4649383      -2.798267    
  19          31 -0.8860437      -1.073503    
  19          37 -0.9572746     -0.9297332    
  19          43  -1.515875      -1.190284    
  19          49  -1.218172     -0.7791679    
  19          55  -1.102582     -0.8772109    
  19          61  -1.027370     -0.8195735    
  19          67 -0.8127689     -0.5485391    
  19          73 -0.6441864     -0.4022478    
  19          79 -0.4570150     -0.2033543    
  19          85 -0.3651582     -0.1294938    
  25           1 -0.6054268      -1.217132    
  25           7 -0.7407182      -1.054351    
  25          13 -0.3321512      -1.567139    
  25          19 -0.7483002      -2.253104    
  25          25 -0.5543621      -2.247710    
  25          31 -3.9390892E-02  -2.343734    
  25          37  -1.865113      -2.181415    
  25          43 -0.6020843      -2.038653    
  25          49 -0.7623259     -0.8114057    
  25          55  -1.108817     -0.9892372    
  25          61  -1.052694     -0.8037179    
  25          67 -0.8688669     -0.5916344    
  25          73 -0.7590979     -0.4595649    
  25          79 -0.6104036     -0.1946686    
  25          85 -0.6588074     -9.9366516E-02
  31           1 -0.8138685     -0.3746961    
  31           7 -8.4147170E-02 -0.4973753    
  31          13 -0.4337556      -1.334884    
  31          19 -0.5457593      -1.698407    
  31          25 -0.6577969      -1.845301    
  31          31  -1.668889      -1.828117    
  31          37  -1.203819      -2.057196    
  31          43 -0.8879474      -2.134445    
  31          49 -0.8857535      -1.102471    
  31          55  -1.218498     -0.9184581    
  31          61  -1.039025     -0.9237540    
  31          67 -0.9691579     -0.6676291    
  31          73 -0.8615177     -0.5763185    
  31          79  -1.137353     -0.4897482    
  31          85 -0.5943280      6.2492140E-02
  37           1 -0.2393228      -2.732805    
  37           7  1.4593905E-03 -0.2020176    
  37          13 -0.6303372     -0.6133371    
  37          19 -0.1975699      -1.174240    
  37          25  -1.635683     -0.3627254    
  37          31  -1.515109      -1.981583    
  37          37 -0.9375111     -0.9931212    
  37          43  -1.363843      -1.549649    
  37          49  -1.103831      -1.363177    
  37          55  -1.198775      -1.181059    
  37          61  -1.067938      -1.018348    
  37          67  -1.019575     -0.9246353    
  37          73 -0.8779502     -0.7895511    
  37          79 -0.6863562     -0.5990396    
  37          85 -0.2886097      -1.089483    
  43           1 -0.5776793      -1.863631    
  43           7 -0.8106826      0.1502321    
  43          13 -0.2556422      -1.022820    
  43          19  0.4982220     -0.6224557    
  43          25  -1.896362      -2.046345    
  43          31  -1.211233      -1.518835    
  43          37  -1.179512      -1.064433    
  43          43 -0.7514921     -0.7757724    
  43          49  -1.386158      -1.085640    
  43          55  -1.237744     -0.7980262    
  43          61  -1.026357      -1.128340    
  43          67 -0.8532083      -1.149826    
  43          73 -0.7615938      -1.093191    
  43          79  -1.032157      -1.251013    
  43          85  0.1180898      -1.280765    
  49           1  -1.416179      -1.748146    
  49           7  -1.354303     -0.5188729    
  49          13 -0.1323060      0.1955658    
  49          19 -0.7697926     -0.4313597    
  49          25  -1.090581     -0.9820307    
  49          31  -1.288527      -1.482457    
  49          37 -0.6602023      -1.378953    
  49          43 -0.4385801      -1.378801    
  49          49 -0.9442692      -1.078182    
  49          55  -1.032356      -1.220377    
  49          61 -0.8567170      -1.207471    
  49          67 -0.7183477      -1.265018    
  49          73 -0.7031319      -1.422170    
  49          79 -0.7852651      -1.986811    
  49          85 -0.1566966      -1.852246    
  55           1  -3.425642      -6.448854    
  55           7  -1.469432      -2.156902    
  55          13  -1.287400      -1.237925    
  55          19 -0.4426567     -0.1621204    
  55          25 -0.5064512     -0.5391338    
  55          31 -0.8294089      -1.852616    
  55          37 -0.3235397      -1.513118    
  55          43 -0.6228370      -1.469255    
  55          49 -0.3641820      -1.158833    
  55          55 -0.7003435      -1.330863    
  55          61 -0.7077910      -1.501531    
  55          67 -0.8625396      -1.746131    
  55          73 -0.5731955      -2.341928    
  55          79 -0.2062361      -2.510644    
  55          85  0.1337020      -2.625733    
  61           1  -3.594511      -7.119893    
  61           7  -2.916506      -6.654611    
  61          13  -1.526737      -5.768787    
  61          19 -0.8728814      -1.713666    
  61          25 -0.2510585      -1.518069    
  61          31 -0.3304124      -1.740066    
  61          37 -0.6777682     -0.9511366    
  61          43 -0.9548255      -1.906161    
  61          49 -0.2237290      -1.057160    
  61          55 -0.5366179      -1.610021    
  61          61 -0.3388043      -2.533017    
  61          67 -5.2883465E-02  -2.602082    
  61          73  8.4104441E-02  -2.728072    
  61          79  0.3083426      -3.101685    
  61          85  0.6281470      -3.323454    
  67           1  -3.591135      -6.110843    
  67           7  -2.808191      -6.083955    
  67          13  -2.218929      -5.853451    
  67          19  -1.551557      -5.526210    
  67          25 -0.8014249      -4.485489    
  67          31 -0.2734919      -2.635132    
  67          37  6.3866340E-02  -1.407375    
  67          43 -0.5734074      -3.024708    
  67          49 -0.2926151      -3.075855    
  67          55  8.9385703E-02  -2.991796    
  67          61  0.3396000      -2.895279    
  67          67  0.4880296      -2.971023    
  67          73  0.5908360      -3.184648    
  67          79  0.7696878      -3.535027    
  67          85   1.180078      -3.724377    
  73           1  -3.195315      -4.600032    
  73           7  -2.661445      -5.165293    
  73          13  -2.144600      -5.453991    
  73          19  -1.574927      -5.353052    
  73          25 -0.9251302      -5.067198    
  73          31 -0.4386413      -4.627797    
  73          37 -0.1486760      -4.121565    
  73          43 -8.9298077E-02  -3.799821    
  73          49  0.1656444      -3.675627    
  73          55  0.4952539      -3.458287    
  73          61  0.7696480      -3.331255    
  73          67  0.9322686      -3.305074    
  73          73  0.9246070      -3.680920    
  73          79   1.177059      -3.925296    
  73          85   1.434534      -4.003213    
  79           1  -2.478489      -3.738322    
  79           7  -2.199367      -4.388821    
  79          13  -1.998997      -4.846165    
  79          19  -1.682757      -5.056147    
  79          25  -1.212069      -4.917627    
  79          31 -0.7750097      -4.671583    
  79          37 -0.4503339      -4.445899    
  79          43 -6.7934789E-02  -4.259037    
  79          49  0.3466863      -4.121108    
  79          55  0.7716087      -3.834810    
  79          61   1.160804      -3.709754    
  79          67   1.286913      -3.756347    
  79          73   1.337452      -4.116672    
  79          79   1.485781      -4.284969    
  79          85   1.637745      -4.279395    
  85           1  -2.286411      -3.578472    
  85           7  -1.926950      -4.014696    
  85          13  -1.693225      -4.556112    
  85          19  -1.435391      -4.864839    
  85          25  -1.129859      -4.952620    
  85          31 -0.7496938      -4.783909    
  85          37 -0.3693850      -4.655892    
  85          43  4.0247269E-02  -4.621067    
  85          49  0.6217631      -4.493557    
  85          55   1.285700      -4.096997    
  85          61   1.558276      -3.922729    
  85          67   1.736984      -4.029644    
  85          73   1.762489      -4.368790    
  85          79   1.741113      -4.516823    
  85          85   1.786210      -4.364361    
  91           1  -1.992153      -3.462013    
  91           7  -1.543924      -3.709724    
  91          13  -1.160260      -4.089428    
  91          19 -0.8943509      -4.533711    
  91          25 -0.7803432      -4.849048    
  91          31 -0.4351161      -4.924956    
  91          37 -7.1642451E-02  -4.876300    
  91          43  0.5249092      -4.859890    
  91          49   1.223204      -4.581639    
  91          55   1.716675      -4.218869    
  91          61   1.937666      -4.022886    
  91          67   1.963387      -4.261041    
  91          73   2.042464      -4.537063    
  91          79   2.071948      -4.722070    
  91          85   2.073677      -4.249052    
  97           1  -1.938535      -3.435567    
  97           7  -1.470977      -3.447064    
  97          13 -0.8900484      -3.581853    
  97          19 -0.4317943      -4.024282    
  97          25 -0.2391478      -4.587556    
  97          31 -4.8176501E-02  -4.875938    
  97          37  0.3352192      -4.947895    
  97          43  0.9634075      -4.756529    
  97          49   1.574929      -4.427122    
  97          55   1.967954      -4.123986    
  97          61   2.099698      -4.017962    
  97          67   2.158964      -4.377975    
  97          73   1.652494      -2.916106    
  97          79   2.083248      -4.143603    
  97          85   1.686909      -2.099738
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Eddie! The ghosting labels are due to `title` option on `key` command: two plots, two title keys. Surprisingly you use `splot` commands with `notitle`. So, the title key still there but no plot key inside it. Try make your plot using only one `splot` command: `splot "wind.txt" u ($1):($2):(1):($3):($4):(1) w vec lt 1 notitle, "counrty.txt" u ((($1)-282)/12)+1:((($2)+906)/12)+1:1 notitle  w l lt -1 lw 0.5`

Comment: @Eddie, is there a specific reason why you are using `splot` for a 2D-plot? Why not just `plot` without the 3rd dimension?

Comment: I will have a try, thank you! @GRSousaJr

Comment: @theozh I tried to use the plot to plot the wind direction, but there was a larger blank margin around the map.

Comment: @GRSousaJr I can't remove [1:97][1:88] before the file, these numbers help me to locate the region what I want, I added a new map which I removed [1:97][1:88], then you can see.

Comment: @Eddie Could you give a sample of you data to allow us make some tests?

Comment: @Eddie From your fourth situation, add: `set xrange [1:97];  set yrange [1:88]` before your `splot` command.

Comment: @GRSousaJr The data file of country.txt has lost of rows, it's about 44628 rows, I think it is impossible to stick whole data file in this post, so how can I share this data file to you directly?

Comment: @GRSousaJr I try it right now.

Comment: @GRSousaJr The result is the same as the second situation. Sorry, it is too late, I am gonna sleep. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this data](http://www.gnuplotting.org/data/world_50m.txt) from [gnuplotting.org/](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-the-world-revisited/) and your data to wind direction, this little code...

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo size 600,600
set output "world_n_wind.png"
unset tics
set size ratio -1
set xrange [1:97]
set yrange [1:88]

set key at 92,13 title "title key"
set title "title plot"

wind  = "wind_direction.txt"
world = "world_50m.txt"

plot \
    world u 1:2     w l   lt 1 not ,\
    wind  u 1:2:3:4 w vec lt 2 not
```

... generates this plot:

[image: plot]

As pointed out by [@theozh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497891/ghosting-keys-appeared-in-gnuplot-map#comment108793161_61497891), you don't need `splot` but only `plot` command.